# Dropdown floats over content while scrolling

Tags: angular, telerik, dropdown

The dropdown floats over content when open and the site is scrolled down or up. A telerik dropdown control is used.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM5iJ.jpg)

It should stay under/over the dropdown-box. Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?
And if I can't prevent it, how can I close it when I start scrolling?

dropdown code:

```
<gd-ui-core-inputs-wrapper [control]="control" [ngClass]="{'error-element-no-label': !labelText}">
  <gd-ui-core-inputs-label
    *ngIf="labelText"
    [text]="labelText"
    [forControlWithId]="controlId"
    [isRequired]="isRequired"
  >
  </gd-ui-core-inputs-label>

  <kendo-combobox
    #dropdown
    *ngIf="control"
    [id]="controlId"
    [formControl]="control"
    [data]="listItems"
    [valueField]="hasId ? 'id' : 'value'"
    [textField]="'description'"
    [clearButton]="canClear"
    [popupSettings]="{ popupClass: 'combobox-popup' }"
    [ngClass]="{'control-with-label':labelText}"
    [itemDisabled]="itemDisabled"
    [valuePrimitive]="allowCustom"
    [allowCustom]="allowCustom"
    [filterable]="filterable"
    [suggest]="suggest"
    [virtual]="virtualSettings"
    [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings"
    (selectionChange)="onSelectionChanged($event)"
  >
    <ng-template *ngIf="hasOptionDisplaySet()" kendoComboBoxItemTemplate let-dataItem>
      <div class="text-truncate">{{ dataItem.optionDisplay }}</div>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-combobox>
</gd-ui-core-inputs-wrapper>
```

Comment: Please share your code. On top, I wonder what "Tarifgrundlagen" and "Schätzung" means :face_with_monocle:

Comment: can you share the code for that dropdown?

Comment: I added the code for the dropdown now

Comment: You can change `top` value for `ng-template` to position the options below the textbox.

Comment: @Vignesh It still stays at the same place after I scroll down or up. It should move with the content.